# Headers Already sent Yii2 error, unable to resolve it using any of the suggested methods

Tags: json, yii2

This might be repeated questions, but I have tried all possible methods to resolve this error in Yii2 without any success

I have my base controller and function as written below in it

```
     /**
     * Send given object as json object
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return json
     */
    public function sendJsonResponse($data) {
        ob_start();
        ob_clean();
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
        die;
    }
```

I call this function in any of the child controllers like

```
return $this->sendJsonResponse(['message'=>'Some message here','status'=>true]);
```

With this I get headers already sent error all the time, tried ways suggested by Yii2 community to change echo to return etc. but in vain.

Please suggest.

Comment: you cant `echo json_encode` now it was in the older version of Yii2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ScaisEdge, thank you for your answer, for some weird reasons, your suggested method does not yield expected results whenever we are using ajax, not sure why so modified my method as given below

```
/**
 * Send given object as json object
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @return json
 */
public function sendJsonResponse($data) {
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return $data;
}
```

This is working as expected, I will post confirmation on whether this resolves the headeralreadysent error that I was originally getting.

Comment: This is working now as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try using return and not echo
(and avoid die())

```
public function sendJsonResponse($data) {
    ob_start();
    ob_clean();
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

anyway check if in your controller you are using others `return` or `echo` for other value somewhere in your code and refactor your code for avoid this.

You should send all the value just in one return